# Escape key not working on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: keyboard, 20.10

Ever since I upgraded my Lenovo W550S laptop to Ubuntu version 20.10 my <kbd>Esc</kbd> (escape key) is dead in the water. Initially, I had issues with keys, <kbd>7</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd>,<kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> but I resolve that by going back to kernel version of 5.8.0-25-generic however <kbd>Esc</kbd> is dead. I searched and searched how to address this issue and so far found nothing. The chassis type of # 10 as I get when running `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type` so it is not 31 or 32 as posted in some hardware related question for those who had other keyboard issues where if 32 or 32 you are pretty much foobar.